# Fetch POST Unexpected end of input Erorr

Tags: javascript, api, reactjs, http-post, redux

I'm trying to do a POST request for authentication in Redux and I'm passing email & password as the body but it returns this error in the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

I looked around for the answer and many people suggested that it might be a missing `}` brace but I looked for it and I don't think it's that.

Here is my fetch function.

```
export function loginUser(creds) {

  let config = {
    mode: 'no-cors',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    body: `email=${creds.email}&password=${creds.password}`
  };


  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(requestLogin(creds));
    return fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/authenticate', config)
    .then(response =>
      response.json()
      .then(user => ({ user, response }))
    ).then(({ user, response }) =>  {
      if (!response.ok) {
        dispatch(loginError(user.message));
        return Promise.reject(user);
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('id_token', user.token);
        dispatch(receiveLogin(user));
      }
    });
  };
}
```

The fetch POST method calls the API and I see it in the networking tab and I see the response too but the fetch request stops at `.then(response =>` after the url and config.

It's been two days and still can't find the solution. By the way, this works fine in Postman(chrome extension), so nothing wrong with the API.

Thanks

Answer EDIT: The issue was related to CORS, so for anyone having the same issue as I did.

Comment: What is `response.json()`?

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN It's the response of the API and includes lots of info about the request, e.g. whether successful or unsuccessful and data if successful etc.

Comment: But you are using json method on responce.Isnt it?

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN yes I'm.

Comment: Is there any method name json in this responce?If it is not then its wrong one.Please remove it

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN I don't think you understand promise based API calls. 
Here read this: https://davidwalsh.name/fetch
response is provided by fetch and it comes with a set of methods and one of them is `.json()`

Comment: Please check it by adding debugger at the same place.You will get an idea

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN Cheers man. Although, what you said wasn't the answer but that lead me to my answer. I had issue with CORS as I was not allowing it in my local API and now it works. 
G'day :)

Comment: You are not returning response.json() in first then()

Comment: did you find solution for it ?

Answer (score 1):

I solve the same question when I remove

```
mode: 'no-cors'
```

from the config.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway you could simplify your snippet code to:

```
fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/authenticate', config)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(({ user, response }) =>  {
```

And you should might add catch method to handle an Error object.